# Spring default transactionManager not found when using JmsTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, spring-transactions

I have a Spring Boot app, where I use JMS with Database. I'm trying to configure `JmsTransactionManager` to use with default TransactionManager (for JPA). I defined the bean in the `@SpringBootApplication` file (that means it has `@Configuration` and `@EnableTransactionManagement`):

```
  @Bean(name="jmsTransactionManager")
  public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
    jmsTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return jmsTransactionManager;
  }
```

That's the only bean I configure by myself for JMS because other configuartion spring-boot does automatically, I just have properties in the `application.yaml` so I assume `connectionFactory` will be autowired. And I want it to use like this:

```
@Transactional(transactionManager = "jmsTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
void do(){
 sendJms();
 saveDb();
}

@Transactional // uses default JPA TM
void sendDb(){
 ...
}
```

So the logic is that I will send to Jms first, then save something to DB, so I need two separate transactions but I want to close the DB transaction before JMS transaction. Maybe it's not correct to make calls like this in such situation, but I don't know how to do it else using declarative transaction management. And the problem is that when I'm defining `JmsTransactionManagement` the default one, that works with DB stops working, but without a `JmsTransactionManagement` transactions to db work:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching TransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier
 match nor bean name match!
```

Am I missing something? I have `spring-data-jpa` in pom so default `transactionManager` configures by spring boot, but it can't find it, why? Unfortunately didn't find the answer on how to do something like that on the StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming that you are not using two phase commit (XA) transactions. Essentially in order to chain transactions between multiple transactional resources, both your jms ConnectionFactory and db Datasource have to be an XA resource implementation, and you have to use proper JTA TransactionManager. While it is not particularly hard thing to do, JTA is usually skipped by majority of java programmers as in normal historical situation (spring code deployed in JEE serer) JTA "just works" in background never to be directly accessed by java programmer. In standalone boot application you have to explicitly enable this functionality by providing proper JTA transaction manager and using XA implementation of your resources.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html

In short JMSTransactionManager and DBTrasnactionManager wont do as you need instance of JTATransactionManager.